# Strategies for dealing with large remote files, and slow networks

Tags: linux, bash, curl, download, bandwidth

So, here's the basic problem, I need to distribute qcow2 images, to a bunch of remote machines; no big deal, right?  Well, the complication is that some of these happen to rely on 4/5G modems, and downloading 5-10G every night just isn't going to work.

The solution I came up with below works perfectly well, but it doesn't feel like the best way to do it.  Does anyone else have a better solution?

remote-hash:

```
#!/bin/bash

RX_AMT=1 # How many kilobytes to recv
RX_OFFSET=0 # How many kilobytes to skip

# Create Temporary files
FILE_HEADERS=$(tempfile)
HASH_FILE=$(tempfile)

# Read the first RX_AMT Kb from the remote file, 
# And set the target download rate to RX_AMT/Second
curl -m 30 --limit-rate ${RX_AMT}k \
    -C $(( $RX_OFFSET * 1024 )) \
    -LD $FILE_HEADERS \
    -so /dev/stdout "$@" | \
    head -c $(( $RX_AMT * 1024 )) > $HASH_FILE

# Append the headers you expect will change when the file does,
# such as content-size or filename to the hash file
egrep -i 'content-length|location|filename' $FILE_HEADERS | \
    grep -v '[.]boxcloud[.]' >> $HASH_FILE
    # boxcloud addresses are nonces, so we dump them

# Return the sha256 of the hash file,
# trimming off everything training the hash
sha256sum < $HASH_FILE | sed -r "s/ *- *$//"

# Best effort to clean up our temporary files
rm $FILE_HEADERS $HASH_FILE 2> /dev/null
```

Currently, I'm using the output of that script to check to see if the remote file has changed without having to actually download the whole thing.  The files I'm downloading are encrypted, so I'm likely to detect any changes to the archive from examining a couple of chunks.  File size alone isn't a good metric for me to use either, and I'm extracting this archive on the fly, and not storing it anywhere (plus, it's encrypted, so it will only vary in length by blocksize_chunks)

Comment: Would `rsync` work? It's built for easy resumption, and verifies up/downloads.

Comment: If I were hosting the images on my own servers, yes, that would be ideal; Unfortunately, in this case I have to store them on a server that doesn't give enough information to determine if a file has changed or not just by looking at the headers.

Comment: zsync might work too.  zsync stores the metadata rsync generates in a separate file.

Comment: I'll take a peek at the manfile, and see if that'll work.  I'd rather be able to stream the file without having to write it to disk as an intermediate step as well (I'm somewhat space limited as well)